# Control multiple (10+) monitors at the same time?

Tags: gpio, display

I want to make an art installation where there's an array of monitors are displaying graphic rendered by a single machine. In the picture I shown, each little square represent a monitor, and the graphic is rendered in real time.

Essentially, I want to control many monitors with a single Raspberry pi. What's the best setup for this (both software and hardware)? After some search I found [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html), is this the right library for this kind of task?

[image]

Comment: connect the controller Raspberry Pi to 10+ Raspberry Pi, each with its own monitor

Comment: pigpio is for handling GPIO - which won't help you attach 16 monitors to a single raspberry pi

Comment: Each RPi4B can control two monitors, so you'll need half as many RPis as you have monitor. https://piwall.co.uk/ (no sure if that's a dead project) gives you the software to sync between multiple RPis.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a physical limit on the number of monitor a raspberry  can control? If not, I think I will try the piwall method. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58927021/how-to-display-image-on-secondary-monitor-in-full-screen) seems to able to control two different monitor using threading. Do you think it's possible extend this idea (PyQt5 and threading) to multiple monitors? The graphic being displayed is low quality and doesn't need to be sync precisely.

Comment: there is a way that you could use only one RPi ... use video wall monitors ... feed the same video to all 16 monitors ... the monitors themselves are configured to each display only a 1/16 of the whole image

Comment: @jsotola that's an interesting approach. Roughly, how would I implement that? in order to have each screen to display only 1/16 of the whole image, do I need to configure that in the monitor's side?